# sudo timestamp_type ppid vs tty

Tags: linux, security, sudo

Assume I have a script a.sh with the content below:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo ls <some_unprivileged_path>
```

If I execute **sudo** command and execute **a.sh** immediately after that 'sudo' do not ask my password because of the **"timestamp_timeout."**

I am trying to prevent this situation, I have tried some configurations so far and achieved preventing this by changing **timestamp_type** to **ppid**.

Related part of the "man sudoers":

```
ppid    A single time stamp record is used for all processes with the same parent process ID (usually the shell).  Commands run from the same shell (or other common parent process)
                               will not require a password for timestamp_timeout minutes (5 by default).  Commands run via sudo with a different parent process ID, for example from a shell script, will be
                               authenticated separately.


tty     One time stamp record is used for each terminal, which means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately.  If no terminal is present, the behavior is the same as
                               ppid.  Commands run from the same terminal will not require a password for timestamp_timeout minutes (5 by default).
```

Since shell forks to execute a command it seems it is a little bit safer than the default. However I am not sure, are there any security problems using ppid rather than the default ?

(I know there are a lot safer tools or habits, however I am trying to understand 'sudo' and some concepts of unix a little bit more)

Comment: `sudo -k`? `man sudo`.

Comment: Actually 'sudo -k' doesn't fit my question. I want to be able to use sudo without password 'before timestamp expires' only within the same shell and not in the forked processes by the shell.

Comment: You seem to have already answered you question: "Commands run via sudo with a different parent process ID, for example from a shell script, will be authenticated separately." Does this not behave the way you expect?